# how to catch postgresql exception in JPA DAO

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I had function used by sequence in psql, to fill new records in **user_ext** table with uid_number from 1000 to 11000 and I need to throw some kind of exception when I had 10000 records and I tried to add another one.

I did this in DB like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uid_func(_seq regclass)
  RETURNS integer AS
$func$
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(uid_number) FROM user_ext)>=10000 THEN
     RAISE EXCEPTION 'Uid numbers pool has been exhausted';
    ELSE
   LOOP
      PERFORM nextval(_seq);
      EXIT WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1000 FROM user_ext WHERE uid_number = lastval());
   END LOOP;
   RETURN lastval();
   END IF;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Next I need to catch this error in JPA DAO. 
In Java i use some function (recalculateUsers) that adds records to **user_ext** table by NativeQuery so when recalculateUsers cannot add another record exception should be thrown and later handled in java.

My question is: How to catch RAISE EXCEPTION in my DAO?

I tried:

```
catch (SQLException ex) {
```

but I got

```
SQLException is never thrown in the corresponding try block
```

Here is method in my DAO:

```
public void refreshUsersPrivileges(List<String> userNames) {
        try {
            em.flush();
            Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT cast(recalculateUsers(?) AS text)");
            query.setParameter(1, StringUtils.join(userNames, "|"));
            query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (PersistenceException ex) {
            throw new InternalUnexpectedException(GENERIC_DAO_COMPONENT, MessageUtil.getMessage(USER_MESSAGE_BUNDLE,
                    "Common.UserMessage.InternalUnexpectedException.UnexpectedCondition"), ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            final String ss = ex.getMessage();

            if (ss.equals("Uid numbers pool has been exhausted")) {

                throw new InternalUnexpectedException(GENERIC_DAO_COMPONENT, MessageUtil.getMessage(USER_MESSAGE_BUNDLE,
                        "Common.UserMessage.InternalUnexpectedException.UnexpectedCondition"), ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see one `try` and two `catch`

Comment: @bmarkham this is correct if you want to catch exceptions of different types.

Comment: No JPA method would/should throw a SQLException ... look at the JPA spec.